# Why is my 1280x800 mdpi device pulling non sw600dp layouts

Tags: android

So I was having trouble in a previous app I am developing so I made something smaller to test.  I created a 1280x800 MDPI emulator and ran it with a "main_layout" layout in port, land, and sw600dp.  Now based on the DPI and the dimensions it should be pulling from the sw600dp but it is actually pulling from my port and landscape layout folders.  I tested this by just setting the tags and printing them to see which layout I am using.

For port and land I have "small" as the tag and sw600dp the tag is "big".  When I print out the tag I get : "small".  But shouldnt a device like this be pulling from sw600dp?

Comment: Unfortunately the `sw` qualifiers were not introduced until API 13: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926281/sw600dp-quantifier-not-working-on-galaxy-tab

Comment: @kcoppock OMG awesome answer kcoppock.  Please post this as an answer and I give you millions of acceptances, actually just 1 because that is all SO lets me do.  Now I know I need /layout-xlarge-land/ for landscape AND /layout-xlarge-port for tablets pre-3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly the `sw` qualifiers (which are so incredibly useful) were not introduced until API level 13 (Android 3.2). So on API 12, these folders will not be respected.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8935720/321697