# Tablet UI not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working on an app that presents a grid of popular movies to the users and when the user clicks on one of the items, it shows the details of the movie.

The app is working fine on phones but my tablet UI implementation is not working

**I don't get any crashes** as such it's just that when I tap on a movie, the **Details don't show up on tablets.**

**Here's the link to the GitHub repo** - https://github.com/Hackertronix/Project-Motion/tree/Stage_2?files=1

**And here are the files which concern with the Tablet UI**

**activity_movies.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager_container">

</FrameLayout>
```

**activity_movies.xml (layout-sw600dp )**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_container">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/details_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
        </FrameLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**MoviesActivity.java**

```
package com.execube.genesis.views.activities;

import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.transition.Explode;
import android.view.View;


import com.execube.genesis.R;
import com.execube.genesis.model.Movie;
import com.execube.genesis.views.fragments.DetailsFragment;
import com.execube.genesis.views.fragments.PopularMoviesFragment;
import com.execube.genesis.views.fragments.TopRatedMoviesFragment;
import com.execube.genesis.views.fragments.ViewPagerFragment;


public class MoviesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PopularMoviesFragment.openDetailsListener,
        TopRatedMoviesFragment.openDetailsListener{


    boolean isTablet;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies);


        if (findViewById(R.id.details_container) == null)//CHECKING FOR TABLET CONFIGURATION
        {
            isTablet=false;
        }
        else{
            isTablet=true;
        }
        View view= findViewById(R.id.viewpager_container);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment;
        fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.viewpager_container);

        if(savedInstanceState==null)
        {
            fragment= new ViewPagerFragment();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.viewpager_container,fragment)
                    .commit();

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void openDetails(Movie movie,ActivityOptions options) {

        //options parameter is for the transition

        if(isTablet)
        {
           //TODO Retain the transitions.

          Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable("PARCEL",movie);

            DetailsFragment fragment= new DetailsFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.details_container,fragment)
                    .commit();
}

        else{
            Intent intent= new Intent(this,DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("PARCEL",movie);
            startActivity(intent,options.toBundle());
        }

    }
}
```

**DetailsActivity.java**

```
package com.execube.genesis.views.activities;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.transition.Fade;
import android.transition.Slide;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;

import com.execube.genesis.R;
import com.execube.genesis.views.fragments.DetailsFragment;

/**
 * Created by Prateek Phoenix on 5/1/2016.
 */
public class DetailsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.details_status_bar));
            Slide slide=new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            slide.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground,true);
            slide.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground,true);
            getWindow().setEnterTransition(slide);
            postponeEnterTransition();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment= fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.details_container);

        if(fragment==null)
        {
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putParcelable("PARCEL",
                    getIntent().getParcelableExtra("PARCEL"));

            fragment = new DetailsFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.details_container,fragment)
                    .commit();

        }

    }
}
```

**DetailsFragment.java**

```
package com.execube.genesis.views.fragments;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.execube.genesis.R;
import com.execube.genesis.model.Movie;
import com.execube.genesis.model.Review;
import com.execube.genesis.utils.API;
import com.execube.genesis.utils.OkHttpHandler;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Response;


/**
 * Created by Prateek Phoenix on 4/30/2016.
 */
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "DETAILS";
    private static final int DEFAULT_NUM_COLORS = 5;
    private Movie mMovie;
    public Intent intent;

    private TextView mDetailTitle;
    private TextView mReleaseDate;
    private TextView mOverview;
    private TextView mOverviewHeader;


    private ImageView mBackdrop;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private RatingBar mRatingBar;

    private ArrayList<Review> mReviews;


    public DetailsFragment() {

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);


        mBackdrop = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.details_poster);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        mDetailTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail_title_text);
        mReleaseDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.release_date);
        mOverview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.overview);
        mOverviewHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.overview_header);

        mRatingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_rating);


        Bundle bundle=getArguments();
        mMovie=bundle.getParcelable("PARCEL");


        String id = String.valueOf(mMovie.getId());
        String reviewQueryUrl = API.MOVIES_BASE_URL + id + "/reviews" + API.API_KEY;
        String trailerQueryUrl = API.MOVIES_BASE_URL+id+"/videos"+API.API_KEY;

        mDetailTitle.setText(mMovie.getTitle());
        mReleaseDate.setText(mMovie.getReleaseDate());
        mRatingBar.setProgress((int) mMovie.getVoteAverage());
        mOverview.setText(mMovie.getOverview());


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != 21) {
            Typeface fontBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Gotham-Rounded-Bold.ttf");
            Typeface fontMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Gotham-Rounded-Medium.ttf");
            Typeface fontMediumLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Gotham-Rounded-Book_.ttf");


            mDetailTitle.setTypeface(fontBold);
            mReleaseDate.setTypeface(fontMedium);
            mOverview.setTypeface(fontMediumLight);
            mOverviewHeader.setTypeface(fontBold);
        }


        OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler(reviewQueryUrl, mCallback);
        handler.fetchData();

        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(API.IMAGE_URL + API.IMAGE_SIZE_500 + mMovie.getPosterPath())
                .into(mBackdrop);
        getActivity().startPostponedEnterTransition();


        return view;
    }

    private okhttp3.Callback mCallback = new okhttp3.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            //TODO handle failure on UI thread
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException,IllegalStateException{

            try {
                String jsonResponse= response.body().string();
                Log.v(TAG,jsonResponse );
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                int resultCount = jsonObject.getInt("total_results");
                if (resultCount != 0) {
                    mReviews = parseReviews(jsonObject);
                } else
                    mReviews = null;

            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }
            catch (IllegalStateException e){}
        }
    };

    private ArrayList<Review> parseReviews(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {


        ArrayList<Review> Reviews = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray reviewsJSONArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

        for (int i = 0; i < reviewsJSONArray.length(); i++) {

            Review review = new Review();
            JSONObject reviewJson = reviewsJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

            review.setId(reviewJson.getInt("id"));
            review.setAuthor(reviewJson.getString("author"));
            review.setContent(reviewJson.getString("content"));
            review.setTotalResults(reviewJson.getInt("total_results"));

            Reviews.add(review);
        }

        return Reviews;
    }


}
```

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8935720/6386583) answer help you?

Comment: Not really, my min sdk is 17

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write same xml file for mobile and tablet in layout and 
layout-sw600dp folder. System will pick by folder name. If you will open in phone it picks up layout from layout folder and if you will open in tablet it picks up 
layout from layout-sw600dp folder.

Comment: I didn't get you. If I have the same xml for tablet and phone then how would the system pick which one to use?